# PHP regular expression [ replace ]

Tags: php, html, regex, replace

Ask to help with two cases with regular expressions in html code edition [ parsing ]

Now I use parser with the next logic (example below with YouTube)

select the unique fragment (ED96RtfF22E) of source html code from YouTube and put it into internal tag [YouTube] on my website

SOURCE :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ED96RtfF22E" frameborder="0 "allowfullscreen> </iframe>
```

USE :

```
replace|0|#<iframe[^>]*youtube\.com\/embed\/([^"]*)"[^>]*>[^<]*<\/iframe>#|[YouTube]$1[/YouTube]|1|
```

based on this logic need to solve issue below:

### Case #1

**replacement the part of html code with images**

SOURCE: have incorrect tale after .jpg (?12345)

```
<img alt="" src="xxx.com/ooo.jpg?12345">
```

NEED: "src" tag without this tale like this `<img alt="" src="xxx.com/ooo.jpg">`

```
replace|0|...|...|1|
```

parts marked here as "..." is a places for php regular expressions for changes.
I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: There are many tools that helping to build right expression. Type in google "regex online'.

Comment: [do not use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: This is kind of unclear seriously. Bigger text doesn't make it more evident.

Comment: Why use regex for these very specific functions? The first one could simply be gotten using `explode()` and `array_reverse()` and the second one is a simple `explode()` - granted you would need to get the `src`-element, and for that there are several methods, but regex is not something I would use for such simple tasks.

Comment: There's no need to bold and header-ify large parts of your question. It's not going to make us more likely to answer your question.

Comment: No problem) Just want to make text more convenient for viewing

Answer (score 1):

For first case: [`<img.*src=\"[^?]*).*(\">)`](https://regex101.com/r/Up7Uh3/1) and replace with `\1\2`.

---

For second case: [`<iframe.*src=\".*embed\/(.*?)\".*?<\/iframe>`](https://regex101.com/r/Up7Uh3/3) and replace with `[YT]\1[/YT]`.

If you don't want to replace then use:

```
preg_match('/<iframe.*src=\".*embed\/(.*?)\".*?<\/iframe>/', $input, $match);
$output = "[YT]" + $match[1] + "[/YT]"
```

Comment: Nicolas, thanks for your answer! Changed my description of issue after I saw it, pls re read it